# Expected prediction error

Tags: statistics

In the case of linear regression where $x_0$ is an input vector, and $Y_0=f(x_0)+\epsilon_0$, i don't understand this formulation of the expected prediction error, with : $\hat{f}(x_0)=x_0 ^T\hat{\beta}$ and $f(x_0)=x_0 ^T\beta$
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\big[(Y_0 - \hat{f}(x_0))^2\big]=\sigma^2 + \mathbb{E}\big[(x_0 ^T\hat{\beta} - f(x_0))^2\big]
\end{equation}
i don't get what is random in $(x_0 ^T\hat{\beta} - f(x_0))^2$, hence why we're taking its expectation. 
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

$\hat \beta$ is random in $( x_0^T \hat \beta - f(x_0 ))^2$.

Remember, $\hat \beta$ is the **estimator** of $\beta$, calculated from your training data. Since your training data is random, $\hat \beta$ is random too.

Comment: oh ok it's clearer now. Thank you